# How can I share an EventBus for a Java and a GWT project at the same time?

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, guava

I have a java project which uses the [Guava EventBus](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained). Now I want to use the code from this project to work with GWT without rewriting it. I know that GWT has its own EventBus but I cannot change the import in my Java project because this would break the Java project.

In my GWT project I included the guava and gwt-guava jars. I also included:

```
<inherits name="com.google.common.collect.Collect"/>
```

in my gwt.xml file. Guava worked at least for other classes (e.g., Strings) in GWT project.

I want to use Guava's EventBus instead of the one provided by GWT. I need this because my Java project will not work with that GWT EventBus. 
The problem is that the GWT project uses the GWT EventBus and the Java Project uses the Guava EventBus. How do I get these things together? It would b great if I could replace the Guava EventBus from the Java project in my GWT project somehow.

**How can How can I use Guava EventBus with GWT?** Is there a way to use it without changing the dependencies in the other Java project?

Comment: What part is not working? What are you trying to achieve? Use Guava's EventBus in place GWT's one? Like in `ActivityManager`, to bind events on widgets, etc.? That obviously won't work, since they don't share any base class.

Comment: @IgorKlimer I want to use Guava's EventBus instead of the one provided by GWT. I need this because my Java project will not work with that GWT EventBus.

Comment: @IgorKlimer The problem is that the GWT project uses the GWT EventBus and the Java Project uses the Guava EventBus. How do I get these things together? It would b great if I could replace the Guava EventBus from the Java project in my GWT project somehow.

Comment: They're not compatible in any way - the have different interfaces, different events, etc. How do you imagine this should work? That's like expecting for one, hmm, chart library to be interchangeable with another, just because they both deal with charts?

Comment: So what would be an alternative solution?

Comment: @IgorKlimer Is there some kind of EventBus I can use for Java and GWT?

Comment: Write your own :) Maybe with some sort of smart usage of a design pattern like adapter or facade, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Guava's `EventBus` isn't available in GWT client code. (You can tell because [it doesn't have the `@GwtCompatible` annotation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/EventBus.html).)

Sometimes a class that's not available under GWT can be made available. `EventBus`, though, uses Java reflection, which is mostly unavailable under GWT, so it can't be made available.

Comment: What else can I use as an EventBus concept for GWT and Java at the same time?

Comment: @confile maybe you can check Errai: http://docs.jboss.org/errai/3.1.1.Final/errai/reference/html_single/#sid-21758054